# Match Ownership in Duplicate Leads

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, field-update, duplicate-management

This is my first question here.
I'm working with a company that allows duplicate leads, but they want all the duplicate leads to have the same owner.
I'm trying to write a before insert, before update trigger, but I can't make it work.
Some help would be awesome!!

Thank you so much!!!

Here's a sample of my trigger.

```
trigger DuplicateLeadOwner on Lead (before insert, before update) {
String leadEmail;
String leadId;
List <Lead> dupeleads = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Email = :leadEmail AND Id != :leadId];
for(Lead l : Trigger.new){
    //Make sure the lead has an email address
    if (l.Email != null){
        //Find a duplicate
        String leadEmail = l.Email;
        String leadId = l.Id;
        
        //If a duplicate is found, update the Owner field.
        if(dupeleads.size() > 0){
            dupeleads[0].OwnerId = l.OwnerId;
            dupeleads[0].Email = l.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to aggregate the emails you want to query, as I demonstrate in my [Aggregate-Query-Update Pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) blog post. Note also that your code was not [bulkified](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk).

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();
Map<String, Id> ownerIds = new Map<String, Id>();
Id ownerId;
// Aggregate Values to Query
for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
  emails.add(record.Email);
}
// Ignore null
emails.remove(null);
// Query matching records
for(Lead record: [SELECT Email, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Email = :emails AND Id != :Trigger.new]) {
  ownerIds.put(record.Email, record.OwnerId);
}
// Update records in trigger
for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
  if((ownerId = ownerIds.get(record.Email)) != null) {
    record.OwnerId = ownerId;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox Thank you so much for the answer!! I'm getting an error with your trigger in the last if statement. It says "Illegal assignment from Boolean to Id". I tried to fix it but couldn't. Could you please check and let me know what's wrong? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @ErnestoPastura There was a missing parentheses, it seems. Try that.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox! Now the syntax is correct, but in stead of changing the ownership of the rest of the duplicates when I assign ownership to one record, it doesn't let me change ownership. It automatically come back the the previous owner. Sorry, but I can't figure out why.